# How do I call an interface method if an object implements that interface?

Tags: java

I have interface Resettable which has method reset(). BaseSystem can implement this interface. Somewhere in code i want to get all systems and reset them if they implement Resettable. Something like:

```
    for (BaseSystem system : world.getSystems()) {
        if (system instanceof Resettable) {
            system.reset();
        }
    }
```

However it doesn't work this way. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast first

```
((Resettable)system).reset();
```